# Coffeescript text highliting with Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, coffeescript, nodeclipse

I have a Coffeescript project that I'd like to edit using Eclipse.

Many people suggested that I should install the Nodeclipse Coffeescript Viewer module in order to have colors and highlights.

I did install the module but I'm still getting a plain black and white file.

What should I do?

Thanks!

PS : I have Eclipse Luna under Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have not installed well, reinstall
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse-coffeescript-viewer-editor-eclipse-431

You would get editor for .coffee files by default.

[image]

Also [Nodeclipse EditBox](https://github.com/nodeclipse/editbox) helps a lot to see indentation

[image]

Comment: It doesn't install the Coffeescript Viewer, it gave me an alert saying that it doesn't exist!

Comment: Indeed. Now fixed, see http://www.nodeclipse.org/#news . You are the first asking this question here. Could be on https://github.com/Nodeclipse/coffeescript-eclipse as well.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a new file, right-click on it and look in the "Open With..." menu. Eclipse will reopen the same editor you used the last time for a given file.

Comment: Thanks @nintind. It gave me a choice between `Text Editor`, `System Editor`, and `In-Place Editor`. No sign of Coffeescript Viewer!